# Make a mongoDB query using OR statement and array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have web interface need to access an URL (shown below) and return only results with requested groups:

```
http://localhost:3000/device/getgroups/group1,group2,group3,group4
```

In MongoDB I have entries with the field 'loc_group'.

I want to return the results only where have the field "loc_group" = group1 OR group2 OR group3 OR group4.

My routes are like this:

```
router.get('/getgroups/:groups', async (req, res) => {
  try {
   
    var groups = "req.parms.groups";
    #split groups 
    var arr = groups.split(",");
    
    #iterate in the results on array (arr)
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i] = ++arr[i];
        if (i = arr.lenght) {
        var query = "{'loc_group': '" + arr[i] + "' }"
        var totals = totals + query;
      } else {
        var query = "{'loc_group': '" + arr[i] + "' },"
        var totals = totals + query;
      }
    }

# after this for, the totals must looks like  
#  "{'loc_group': 'group1' }"
#  "{'loc_group': 'group2' }"
#  "{'loc_group': 'group3' }"
#  "{'loc_group': 'group4' }"
#
# then i try to use it on the mongodb query:

    const logues = await device.find({ $or: [ totals ], })

    res.json(logues)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
  }
})
```

but it's not working, what I get when enter the URL is:

> {"message":"$or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects"}

I am a beginner to nodejs and this is my first question here, if need some other information or something please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. But the main one is basically ignoring the expectations of API you work with. See, MongoDB expects regular JavaScript objects passed in `$or` query. What you give it instead is a concatenation of stringified objects, each created by this expression:

```
var query = "{'loc_group': '" + arr[i] + "' }"
```

... passed into regular array. Apparently, MongoDB couldn't guess what you wanted, hence `$or/$and/$nor entries need to be full objects` error.

So, instead of doing JS work on your own, just use native objects to create a query. In fact, you don't even need $or here, as you're looking for the same property's values. Quoting [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#-or-versus--in):

> When using `$or` with  that are equality checks for the
> value of the same field, use the `$in` operator instead of the `$or`
> operator.

So here's one (simplified) way to do it:

```
router.get('/getgroups/:groups', async (req, res) => {
  const locGroups = req.params.groups.split(',');
  const logues = await device.find({ loc_group: { $in: locGroups } });
  res.json(logues);
}
```

What? Yes, that's essentially it. You might consider adding some validation and error handling to this code, and may be some logging, too, but it should be a middleware concern anyway, so the controller stays THAT simple. And that's the beauty - and the reason of existence - of the modern backend-oriented ecosystems: easy things should stay easy.

Comment: just removed the [ ] and it worked very well. I have alot to learn.

Comment: Argh, totally forgot `locGroups` is an array on its own, so [] are not needed indeed. As you can see, we all have something to learn sometimes; the most important thing is never giving up. )